# Review my simple database tables

Tags: database-design

Hey trying to create a simple database table for a small beer review project, it been awhile since i have created db's so could anyone just tell me if i am totally wrong here?

Especially my use of unique identifiers, as i see it they would always be unique?

Project description: A simple asp.net site containing beer data, and information on specific key elements like brewery etc. people should be able to search by name and read about the beer.

[image: Picture of simple database]

Comment: you need to specify more about your project to know if your DB design is O.K

Comment: I'm not sure why you need `uniqueidentifier` here. Why wouldn't a simple auto-increment number work for you?

Comment: auto-increment number would also work, but wasnt sure how to do so, in sql some uniqueID's has the (newid()) as default value.

Comment: #jcho i added a small project description

Comment: I can't work out why you have the separate `beerData` table - isn't everything in there appropriate to the `beer` record?  And what's `beerType`?As @jcho360 says, without more detail behind your decisions, it's hard to say if your design is OK.

Comment: Beer data contains information about alc. % etc. and beertype is the type of beer. i am not really sure why i pulled them into separate tables, especially beerdata, with beertype its the idea that one can read about the different types and then mayne see which beer is defined by that type.

Comment: @dahund: Having the detailed info in a separate table *could* be useful if it is quite likely that you won't always be populated. If you expect to *almost* always get *most* of this data, I'd suggest merging `beerData` into `beer`.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner thx i totally agree iam not really sure what i was thinking.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about your data I'm not sure about your table structure, but I will say that GUIDs/uniqueidentifiers are controversial for clustered indexes.  Traditional logic says that your clustered index should be unique, small, and sequential.  GUIDs are unique, large, and random.  (There is a newsequentialID() function that you could use as a default value to get around the random bit, however.)

An article against random GUIDs as PK/clustering keys:  http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/guids-as-primary-keys-andor-the-clustering-key/  Summary:  Your data can end up a scrambled mess, and selects of ranges that should be next to each other can be slowed down.  Also, it takes up too much space in large tables and indexes.

An article for random GUIDs as PK/clustering keys:  http://blog.kejser.org/2011/10/05/boosting-insert-speed-by-generating-scalable-keys/  Summary:  If you have a LOT of inserts, it might be faster to spread them out instead of having them all be "at the end."

Personally, I think that if you have a specific business/logic reason to use GUIDs, then use them.  Otherwise, you might want to consider using an autonumber column instead.

Comment: Clustered indexes over non-sequential `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` types (or where such a UUID is the first key in the index) are generally a bad idea due to page splits leading to bad fragmentation and so forth, but your primary key does not have to be a a clustered index. For many tables where PK searches are usually for a single item it is better to use the single clustered index elsewhere (on column(s) that you regularly perform ranged queries on).

Comment: Thank you so much, you give a good argument for not using uniqueidentifiers. Would you instead recommend using "ID int  IDENTITY(1,1)" instead?

Comment: I would, yes.  It definitely meets the unique, small, sequential criteria.